# Knee pain after summer training

Tags: running

I did write a long winding entry, but decided to replace it with this. Please help.

23 year old male, 1.80 m, 79 kg
Running 3+ years (~75 km/mo)
Swimming 2+ years 
Cycling 1 year

This Summer finally entered some events (triathlons, fun runs, open water swims etc). I didn't increase my distances or overall training much, if anything I took more rest days before and after events.

Developed pains in both knees over the Summer. Initially dull ache, then bruises underneath the knees, then burning pain on the inside-leg side of the kneecap and along the entire outside-side of the knee. Sometimes feels like a warm trickle(?) when resting/walking.

Read online, thought it was a generic "runners knee", took 3 weeks off from all physical activity. Started running again gently (2 mile jogs etc) and pain is back straight away. My current running shoes only have a couple hundred km on them if that and are the same type I've used for years.

Basically the pain feels like a dull burn in my knees. I can run and walk on them, but even when stretched out on the sofa there's a constant presence in them. I don't know whether it's patellas or tendonitis or ITBS or the myriad of other options I've read about. I would see a physiotherapist but ideally anything I can do to save on an expensive visit would be very helpful (recent graduate here).

Any advice people can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: My immediate thought is that your bike position is wrong, it's easy to get knee issues if your fit is not right. But, the symptoms (Especially the fact that they persist when at rest) and severity leads me to say that really is something that needs to be checked out.

Comment: I think that this question should be closed. Fitness.SE is not a place to ask for medical advice. Go see a doctor.